# Ruby in Rails - dynamically mapping in a .map

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

**EDIT**:
For clarification, I want the number of elements of the resultant array-of-arrays to change dynamically based on the # of platforms. I.e. I want [[35,"assetname","platname1","platname2","platname3"]], not [[35, "assetname, ["platname1", "platname2", "platname3"]]].

I am using datatables as a part of my Rails app. I have a method that generates an ActiveRecord association and passes it to map. The operative code looks like this:

```
assets.map do |asset|
[
  asset.id,
  asset.name,
  asset.thing
]
```

But I want to do something trickier - I want to dynamically make **the number of entries in the resultant array** to be larger based on the # of some other object. I have an object called Platforms... so something like this

```
assets.map do |asset|
[
  asset.id,
  asset.name,
  Platforms.all.each do |line|
     line.platform_name.to_s,
  end
]
```

The problem is... it appears to be a syntax problem. No matter what I do, I cannot get a setup like this to work. I tried to simplify - this works (showing 1 in the final column):

```
assets.map do |asset|
[
  asset.id,
  asset.name,
  [1].each do |line| line.to_s end
]
```

But try to break that out to having more than one element, and no dice:

```
assets.map do |asset|
[
  asset.id,
  asset.name,
  [1,2].each do |line| line.to_s end
]
```

This puts just "1,2" in the final column. Whereas I want 1, then 2 in their own two columns - not "1,2" in a singular column.

As far as the syntax errors I get when trying to do it with my actual object:

app/datatables/assets_datatable.rb:111: syntax error, unexpected keyword_end, expecting '='
app/datatables/assets_datatable.rb:142: syntax error, unexpected keyword_end, expecting ']'

How does one achieve this? What I want to achieve is to have a **resultant array that has more elements** for each # of Platforms.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Assuming you have a model called `Platform` (not `Platforms`, since models are usually in the singular), it seems like this would be as simple as:

```
platform_names = Platform.pluck(:platform_name)

assets.map do |asset|
  [
    asset.id,
    asset.name,
    platform_names
  ]
end
```

Naturally, `platform_names` will be identical for each mapped `asset`, but I guess that's what you want?

Given your comment, you can try:

```
platform_names = Platform.pluck(:platform_name)

assets.map do |asset|
  [
    asset.id,
    asset.name
  ].concat(platform_names)
end
```

Or, as mu says:

```
platform_names = Platform.pluck(:platform_name)

assets.map do |asset|
  [
    asset.id,
    asset.name,
    *platform_names
  ]
end
```

Comment: Hello @jvillian - correct - it is Platform. My problem here is my resultant map is [[35, "assetname, ["platname1", "platname2", "platname3"]]]. I want [[35,"assetname","platname1","platname2","platname3"]]. Sorry if I've made that super unclear - I will update the question here.

Comment: See updated answer. I *think* this is what you're looking for. Maybe.

Comment: Or `[asset.id, asset.name, *platform_names]`, maybe.

Comment: @jvillian Ahhhh - yes - concat works splendidly. And likewise for mu is too short. Either works well - thanks!